# Spring: Nested object does not get deserialized

Tags: java, json, angular

I'm sending a POST-Request from angular to spring. Its getting deserialized mostly correct, but one nested object is getting deserialized as an empty Object.

My Angular interfaces look as follows:

```
// ClientMedicalModal.ts
export interface ClientMedicalModal {
  clientMedicalId: number;
  client: ClientModel;
  medicalEvidence: MedicalEvidence;
}

// ClientModal.ts
export interface ClientModal {
  clientId: number;
}

// MedicalEvidenceModal.ts
export interface MedicalEvidenceModal {
  B001: string;
  B003: string;
  B004: string;
}
```

My Java-Objects look like this:

```
public class ClientMedical implements Serializable {
  private Integer clientMedicalId;
  private Client client;
  private MedicalEvidence medicalEvidence;

  // getter and setter
}

public class Client implements Serializable {
  private Integer clientId;

  // getter and setter
}

public class MedicalEvidence implements Serializable {
  private String B001;
  private String B003;
  private String B004;
  
  public String getB001() {
    return B001;
  }

  public MedicalEvidence setB001(String b001) {
    B001 = b001;
  }
  // all other getter and setter
}
```

When I check the post message from my browser everything seems to be okay:
`{"medicalEvidence":{"B001":"Test","B003":"TestMessage","B004":"Whatever"},"client":{"clientId":1}}`

Debugging in Spring I get the request, there is a Client-Object with clientId = 1, but the ClientEvidence-Object is empty, all B00* fields are null.
[See here the debugging values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GufOQ.jpg)

Spring form binding binds the form parameters to respective fields for Client class, but MedicalEvidence is blank, so Spring instantiates a new MedicalEvidence class with all fields having null values. Why does the parameters does not get bound to the MedicalEvidence's class fields but to Client's class (and all other classes I'm using the same way)? Btw. It does not work either if I just send MedicalEvidence from Angular. The object params are still all empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using b001, b002,.. as names, the first letter should not be uppercase in your use case, except you want to use some annotation. And use 'this.' in the setter method.

```
public class MedicalEvidence implements Serializable {
  private String b001;
  private String b003;
  private String b004;
                 ^^^^
  
  public String getB001() {
    return b001;
  }

  public MedicalEvidence setB001(String b001) {
    this.b001 = b001;
    ^^^^^
  }
```